# rails 3 validation of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

hiho

Is there any way to tell rails that my string may not be 'something'?

I am searching for something like

```
validates :string, :not => 'something'
```

thanks
klump

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Either of these will do the job (click on the methods for documentation):

1. Probably the best and fastest way, easy to extend for other words:

   ```
   validates_exclusion_of :string, :in => %w[something]
   ```
2. This has a benefit of using a regexp, so you can generalise easier:

   ```
   validates_format_of :string, :without => /\A(something)\Z/
   ```

   You can extend to other words with `/\A(something|somethingelse|somemore)\Z/`
3. This is the general case with which you can achieve any validation:

   ```
   validate :cant_be_something
   def cant_be_something
     errors.add(:string, "can't be something") if self.string == "something"
   end
   ```
4. To get exactly the syntax you proposed (`validates :string, :not => "something"`) you can use this code (a warning though, I discovered this while reading the master branch of the rails source and it should work, *but it doesn't work on my ~ 3 months old install*). Add this somewhere in your path:

   ```
   class NotValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
     def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
       record.errors[attribute] << "must not be #{options{:with}}" if value == options[:with]
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Yeah I guess we both covered it pretty exhaustively ;) Using `\A` and `\Z` is probably a safer idea - good catch.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of ways. If you have exact list of what it can't be:

```
validates_exclusion_of :string, :in => ["something", "something else"]
```

If you want to ensure that it doesn't exist as a substring at all:

```
validates_format_of :string, :with => /\A(?!something)\Z/
```

If it is more complicated and you want to hide the messy details:

```
validate :not_something

def not_something
  errors.add(:string, "Can't be something") if string =~ /something/
end
```