# Rails: Validation Containing String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to make it so a field containing some string like "@" will not be allowed, generating an error. Is there a validation for this? If not, how will I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`validates_format_of`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000087).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question here:

[rails 3 validation of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933403/rails-3-validation-of-a-string)