# Validation: Excluding Regexps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can a validation exclude a regexp?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
validates_format_of :string, :without => /\A(something)\Z/
```

which is [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4933515/18706), but I don't think is a real thing (`Unknown validator: 'WithoutValidator`).

Comment: which version of rails are you using ?

Comment: The `:without` option has been there since [August of 2009](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cccb0e6b9327fb562b72007a012933c9c61a33fa). Are you calling `validates_format_of` exactly like in your example?

Comment: Actually no, so that may be it. I was calling `validates :format =>`. I thought they were equivalent and perhaps the validates_* methods deprecated, as the official guide doesn't mention them? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own:

```
validate :name_exclude_pattern

def name_exclude_pattern
  unless self.name !~ /\A(something)\Z/
    errors.add(:name, "invalid format.")
  end
end
```

Though of course, this would have to be done for each attribute you want to check.