# how to disallow integers input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to search and find this on Stackoverflow and Google but have come out short handed. What I am trying to do is simple I have several rows that are text in the database. Thus it should be text. Say for example 'fullname'. I thought the db came with a filter on that but it didn't. My bad.

Take the following example:

I have the :fullname and would obviously like to only allow text. As people's name contains alphabetical characters and not integers. So that I don't end up with people registering as   Snip3rb0yxX.

How do I go about creating a filter in the model that only allows alphabetical characters, plus say space.

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933403/rails-3-validation-of-a-string It is exactly what you need

Comment: @xlembouras I tried something like this:   validates_format_of :name, :with => /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+/  and it doesn't work if I add say '1' after a full name. Any thoughts?

Comment: You will seriously piss of users if you restrict the names people can enter to only `a-z`. Simple examples are umlauts, diacritics, hyphens, ... And believe it or not, people can legitimately have numbers in their names too. Please refer to no. 15 (and all the others) here http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something similar to

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]+(\d+)?\z/
```

in oher words, to allow:

- letters
- a space
- optional numbers at the end
- and only that (exact match in beginning and end)

Comment: got: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Comment: Sweet been stuck on this problem for hours. I should definitely take a deeper dive into regexp at some point